Remove white spaces in quick view form
Hi we added ProviderStatus as quick form view in main form, but it shows white spaces which need to remove. I tried several approaches but does not work:
function formLoad(executionContext) {
    var quickViewControl = formContext.ui.quickForms.get("Provider_Status");
    quickViewControl.setVisible(true);   // this works

    if (quickViewControl && quickViewControl.getControl(0)) {
        if (quickViewControl.isLoaded()) {
            var allElements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-id]');
            let mainContainer = document.querySelector('[data-id="Provider_Status"]');
            let quickFormContainer = mainContainer.querySelector('[data-id="Provider_Status-QuickFormContainer"]');
        }
    }
}

We tried to add

delay, recheck
re execute function in every 500 milliseconds,
Use MutationObserver to watch for DOM changes
quickViewControl.addOnLoad(function() {   - this function not execute

In DOM structure verify all quick view form element loaded, data-id name also verified
still it does not work.

manipulating the DOM directly is not supported inside Dynamics 365 / Dynamics CRM

As mentioned in the comments by Guido Preite do not attempt to modify the DOM of built-in components. It is cumbersome and unsupported and may easily break in future versions of the system.
If you need full control over the visual presentation of components you have the following options:

Create a Custom Page. This is the low code approach.
Create an HTML web resource. Here you basically create your own HTML page. You can add the scripts, css, images and other HTML components you need. Close integration with the hosting model driven form can be challenging, but is possible.
Create a PCF control. Involves a learning curve. Use this when you need a reusable component.

